# Exponential growth problem. Check.

Tags: calculus

> A bacteria culture initially contains 100 cells and grows at a rate proportional to its size. After an hour the population has increased to 420.
>   (a) Find an expression for the number of bacteria after t hours.
>   (b) Find the number of bacteria after 3 hours.

$$y(t) = y_0 \cdot e^{kt}$$ where k is some constant and t is time.

So we can say:

$$420 = 100 \cdot e^{k}$$
$$4.2 = e^{k}$$

$$\ln{4.2} = k$$

So:

a) $y(t) = 100 e^{\ln{4.2}t}$

b) $y(3) = 100 e^{3 \cdot \ln{4.2}}$

Is this right?

Comment: 420 divided by 100 is 4.2

Comment: $k$ is **some constant** and $t$ is **time**.

Comment: Sorry, so many mistakes my firs ttime around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your work is correct.

You may express the solution without logarithms and exponentials as well.

Note that $$y(t) = 100 e^{\ln{4.2}t}= 100(4.2)^t$$

Thus  $$y(3)= 100(4.2)^3$$